# Adding/Removing Search filters dynamically with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I'm currently trying to build a post filter section into a website and need some help with the JavaScript/jQuery that goes along with it. Below you can see an example of the layout visually and the html layout.

The sequence of events will go as follows:

- User selects from the top list of filters (bottom tags are not visible until selected)
- Once selected the "selected tag filter disappears from the top list and is added to the bottom ("circular tags")".
- the user can also delete the tags and they will return to the top list of filters.

The way I imagined this working:

Selecting a filter

- check for "checked checkbox"
- add selected "checkbox" label + value attribute to an array
- get the last values added to the array and create new filter tag underneath under content tag container

Removing a Filter

- user clicks the small x on the tag they wish to remove
- the tag is removed added back to the top list of filters and removed from the array

[image: Filters Preview]

```
<div class="blog-feed-filters">
                <h5>FILTER</h5>

                <div class="checkbox">
                    <input class="checkbox-active" id="check1" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="1">
                    <label for="check1">Turas Application Updates</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="checkbox-active" id="check2" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="2">
                    <label for="check2">General News</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="checkbox-active" id="check3" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="3">
                    <label for="check3">Organisation Updates</label>
                    <br>
                    <input class="checkbox-active" id="check4" type="checkbox" name="filter" value="4">
                    <label for="check4">UI Updates</label>
                </div>
                <hr />
                <div id="content-tag-container">
                    <div class="content-tag">Update <a href="">✕</a></div>
                    <div class="content-tag">Mobile Applications <a href="">✕</a></div>
                    <div class="content-tag">New website update <a href="">✕</a></div>
                    <div class="content-tag">Update <a href="">✕</a></div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

JavaScript/ Jquery Please excuse the mess. I'm a noob:D

```
$('.checkbox-active').click(function () {

//check to see if the checkbox has been "checked"
if (document.getElementById('check1').checked) {

    var filtersSelected = [];

    //get the item that has been checked and add it to an array
    $.each($("input[name='filter']:checked"), function () {
        filtersSelected.push($(this).val() + $("label[for='checkbox-active']").innerText);
    });
    //find the last item in the array
    if (!Array.prototype.last) {
        Array.prototype.last = function () {
            return this[this.length - 1];
        };
    };
    //create a new filter tag and add it to the content-tag-container div 
    for (var c in filtersSelected.last()) {
        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
        newElement.className = "content-tag";
        newElement.innerHTML = "<a href=''>" + "✕" + "</a>";
        document.getElementById("content-tag-container").appendChild(newElement);
    };

}

});
```

Any help is appreciated. Cheers

Comment: So what's the problem?

Comment: @BobBrinks The problem is it doesn't function properly and I'm not sure why

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic

Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @BobBrinks That doesn't help me much does it

Comment: It's supposed to help you ask a better question so other people will help you.

Comment: @Zylo Do you need full functional code or is it ok to give partially working as well?

Comment: @Abhijeet partially working would be fine, I can suss the rest out Thanks

Comment: Ok. I'm only adding the partially running code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made some changes in your javascript :

```
$(document).ready( function() {
    $('.checkbox-active').click(
            function() {
                //console.log("Hi");
                //check to see if the checkbox has been "checked"


                    var filtersSelected = [];
                    //console.log($("input[name='filter']:checked"));

                    //get the item that has been checked and add it to an array
                    var pushed=false;
                    $.each($("input[name='filter']:checked"), function() {
                        //console.log( );
                        filtersSelected.push($(this).val() + $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").text());
                        $("label[for='"+$(this).attr('id')+"']").remove();
                        $(this).remove();
                        pushed=true;
                    });
                    console.log(filtersSelected);
                    //find the last item in the array
                    if (!Array.prototype.last) {
                        Array.prototype.last = function() {
                            return this[this.length - 1];
                        };
                    }
                    ;
                    //create a new filter tag and add it to the content-tag-container div 
                    if(pushed){
                    var c = filtersSelected.last(); 
                        var newElement = document.createElement('div');
                        newElement.className = "content-tag";
                        newElement.innerHTML = c + "<a href=''>" + "X" + "</a>";
                        document.getElementById("content-tag-container")
                                .appendChild(newElement);
                    }


            });
});
```

Above code is partially running to add checked values in filtered list.
Replace your javascript with above code.

Comment: Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: Perfect Thanks for the help, I hopefully will be alright with the rest.